# xp_cmdshell en Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'copy f:\temp\Formatos\Base_PptoER.xls f:\temp\Varios\Base_PptoER.xls'
```

Me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proceso funciona de manera correcta el detalle que tengo es que necesito que al correr esta linea de código no me muestre el resultado de la imagen adjunta, solo que haga su proceso y no me muestre esa notificación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para que no devuelva resultados este procedimiento extendido del sistema tienes la opción `NO_OUTPUT`

De esta forma quedaría así:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'copy f:\temp\Formatos\Base_PptoER.xls f:\temp\Varios\Base_PptoER.xls', NO_OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a [la documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), puedes usar `no_output` para que no devuelva nada al cliente.

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'copy f:\temp\Formatos\Base_PptoER.xls f:\temp\Varios\Base_PptoER.xls', NO_OUTPUT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no querés ver la salida como resultado, lo óptimo es insertar estos datos en una tabla, que eventualmente podría servirte de auditoría:

```
CREATE TABLE #CmdOutput (
   Line VARCHAR(1024)
)

INSERT INTO #CmdOutput (Line)
EXECUTE xp_cmdshell 'copy f:\temp\Formatos\Base_PptoER.xls f:\temp\Varios\Base_PptoER.xls'
```